# Storyboard is not showing Tab Xcode iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I have a problem with storyboard.

I have a tabbar controller combined with a navigation bar controller. I created my app with the help of [this tutorial](http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/).

The first 3 Tabs worked just fine. I created some detail views on the first 3 tabs using seque. Now I would like to have a forth and fifth tab in my tab bar.

So I went back to the tutorial and added tabs. In storyboard everything looks perfect. See [screen](http://files.beger.org/storyboard.tiff). When I build the app, my new tab is not showing up.

I added another one to check if a made a mistake. But same here: it is not showing up.

I created a new project like in the tutorial, and it works! But why not in my old project? Did I screw up some build settings?

Comment: Without code is very unlikely you get a good answer.

Comment: I found the answer. 

I dont know if it is really the answer, but i changed my localization to german and deleated english. Being frustrated i changed it back and it works. 
but why? 
well im happy, but i cant really understand.

Cheers!

Comment: It is possible(but hard to say) that the reason it originally wasn't working was that Xcode needed to clean targets, or the simulator needed to be reset, and changing the localization was enough to push through that changes had been made. If you run into this problem again, try doing what I stated above and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's your situation without code, but I recently added another language to my Storyboard and all changes I made since this were applying only in English Storyboard. So, when I run application on my device (not in English language) I was watching something different than in Storyboard.

Try to change your language to English and tell us what you see.